# Power Query Source Item Not Case Sensitive

Tags: excel, powerquery

Is it possible to have a Power Query `source` statement be case in-sentitive?

For example, I have 10 excel files in a folder that I need to import into my data model; with the desired data in sheets named either `Detail` or `DETAIL`.

I'm using the following statement to reference the sheets, but need to modify it so the query with work for both names:

```
= Source{[Item="DETAIL",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data]
```

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual format is **= try xxx otherwise yyy** so this should work for you

```
  = try Source{[Item="DETAIL",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data] otherwise Source{[Item="Detail",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data]
```

Comment: You can use `= try xxx catch () => yyy` and `= try xxx catch (e) => e[Message]`  -- `otherwise` swallows all exceptions -- it kills any type or error info, meaning you can't save or change the reaction.  -- Like if that row failed because a Web.Contents token expired -- You'd never know

Comment: What does that mean? catch is not a valid M function

Comment: `catch` is not a  `function`, it's a `language-keyword`. The language specs haven't updated it, but Its for handling standard errors. It's part of the `try` expression. It's fully explained here <https://bengribaudo.com/blog/2020/01/15/4883/power-query-m-primer-part-15-error-handling> -- you can use the older `try x` and `try x otherwise z` , but the newer `catch` one is sugar

Answer (score 1):

This will convert `DETAIL` to lowercase, making it insensitive.

```
let
    InsensitiveSource = Table.TransformColumns(
        Source,
        {
            {"Item", Text.Lower, type text},
            {"Kind", Text.Lower, type text}
        }
    ),
    FinalTable = InsensitiveSource{[Item = "detail", Kind = "sheet"]}[Data]
in
    FinalTable
```

For other Power Query functions that are case sensitive, you toggle that on using the argument `Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`

Comment: This is the very solution. Thank you. Actually you should make it as a query step in the Transform Sample File after the first step, named Source: `=Table.TransformColumns(Source,{{"Item", Text.Lower, type text},{"Kind", Text.Lower, type text}})`